# HG Multiple Heads Across Multiple Branches

Tags: mercurial

I have several branches in mercurial all indicating there are multiple heads. When I attempt to execute `hg merge -r $x -r $y` in an attempt to merge two of the revisions I receive and error indicating that there are outstanding uncommitted merges.

Answer (score 0):

It probably happens because you started a merge before but did not commit it. You can undo the previous merge in your working directory by running `hg update -C`.